# How can I separate byte from character?

Tags: java

I have an byte array arrived and it contains normal value from -128 to 127 and also some characters like'O', 'K', space.

How could I seperate them and print at right format? for value, I print value, for character I print 'O', 'K' like a string?

Comment: Well what if you want to receive a value which also happens to be an ASCII character? (For example, a value of 79 which is also the UTF-16 code unit for 'O'.) Basically you shouldn't be mixing binary data with text data without some way of telling which is which...

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right, I found that problem too. but too bad that's what I need to solve.

Comment: You can't "solve" a lack of information. Suppose I send you two messages, both `new byte[] { 79 }`. The first is meant to be "the value 79" and the second is meant to be "the character 'O'". The information in them is the same - if there's no framing information, you clearly can't differentiate between those two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, any byte or any byte combination might be a character depending on your character encoding. You are probably trying to separate the **human-readable** characters.

In that case, a good encoding would be ISO_8859-1 (standard 1 byte encoding):

```
byte[] array = ...; //this is your byte array
String string = new String(array, "ISO_8859-1"); //convert ALL the bytes to characters
```

Now, you can use the [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class to check what kind of characters you have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    char ch = string.charAt(i);
    //now perform your tests on the character
    if(.../*character is good*/) System.out.println(ch);
    else /*character shouldn't be displayed*/ System.out.prinln(((int)ch));
}
```

For example, you can print all the characters that represent valid letters:

```
if(Character.isLetter(ch)) ...
```

I think this should do what you're intending to do, but it's highly questionable why you would do this.